# Was there ever a "flu season" in the Flintstones original TV show or in subsequent works?

Tags: plot-device, the-flintstones

Inspired by the Biology SE question [Was there a flu season in paleolithic times?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/112102/27918).

From Wikipedia's [Paleolithic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleolithic):

> The Paleolithic or Palaeolithic... also called the Old Stone Age (from Greek: παλαιός palaios, "old" and λίθος lithos, "stone"), is a period in human prehistory that is distinguished by the original development of stone tools, and which represents almost the entire period of human prehistoric technology.

which certainly sounds like a dead-ringer for the [Flintstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flintstones) (except of course for the presence of dinosaurs!):

> The Flintstones is an American animated sitcom produced by Hanna-Barbera Productions. The series takes place in a romanticized Stone Age setting and follows the activities of the titular family, the Flintstones, and their next-door neighbors, the Rubbles. It was originally broadcast on ABC from September 30, 1960, to April 1, 1966, and was the first animated series to hold a prime-time slot on television.

**Question:** Was there ever a "flu season" in the Flintstones original TV show or in subsequent works? Was there at least a period of time when there was a flu, or even a cold that was "going around" being transmitted from one person to another?

Comment: The Flintstones isn't stone age, it's "The Honeymooners just different enough to not get sued".  Thus, whatever happened in the working class US 1950s could happen in The Flintstones.

Comment: @RonJohn yes, omg I never made that connection until now, but wow! (Oh, and they had to get rid of "..to the Moon!") Potential follow-up question "Was there ever a rocket ship or reference to going to space in the Flintstones original TV show or in subsequent works?"

Comment: I'm sure you could search the series' Wikipedia episode pages for words like flu, sick and Moon.

Answer (score 16):

The ['Bedrock Bug'](https://flintstones.fandom.com/wiki/The_Bedrock_Bug) (basically a flu-like illness that lasts for 24 hours) made an appearance in the Xmas special, [*A Flintstone Christmas Carol*](https://flintstones.fandom.com/wiki/A_Flintstones_Christmas_Carol) (1994).

---

Captain Caveman came down with a sickness (the titular 'super cold') in the spinoff series *The Flintstone Kids* episode *[Captain Caveman's Super Cold](https://flintstones.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Caveman%27s_Super_Cold)* (1987).

---

Wilma came down with the 'Dinosaur flu' in *The Flintstone Comedy Show* episode [Ugly is Only Skin Deep](https://flintstones.fandom.com/wiki/Ugly_is_Only_Skin_Deep) (1981).